# How should I automatically associate a Kubernetes-provisioned elastic load balancer with a Route 53 alias?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, kubernetes, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

When creating a service of type [LoadBalancer](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#type-loadbalancer) on AWS, Kubernetes auto-provisions an elastic load balancer. I am wondering how I can automatically associate that load balancer with a Route 53 alias?

Alternatively, can I make Kubernetes re-use an elastic load balancer (which I've assigned a Route 53 alias to)?

Comment: Could you specify the service as of type NodePort and specify its [nodePort](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/api/v1/types.go#L1866) to equal the backend port of your existing elb?

Comment: @caesarxuchao Will that work? I have no idea. If you have a working way of doing this, please write it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a project that accomplishes this: https://github.com/wearemolecule/route53-kubernetes

A side note here, there are some issues with being able to select the TLD that this uses, it seems to use the first matching public recordset.

Also this doesn't work with the internal ELBs.  There was an issue opened under the project for this request.

Comment: FYI, the issue with selecting the first match recordset and internal ELB support has been fixed. Also, I should note that this project is being retired in favor of https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns.

Answer (score 1):

K8s cannot automatically associate the ELB with the route 53. You need config that by yourself. As on how to instruct k8s to reuse an existing ELB, there are two ways:

1. [Update: this only works on GCE, **NOT** on AWS] Specify the service type=LoadBalancer, and specify the [ExternalIP](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/api/v1/types.go#L1812) to equal the existing ELB's external IP, and k8s should reuse that ELB. I know this works on GCE, but I haven't tried it on AWS. Also, if this all works, when you delete the k8s service, the ELB will be deleted by k8s as well.
2. Specify the service as of type=NodePort, and specify its [NodePort](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/api/v1/types.go#L1866) to equal the backend port of your existing ELB. I have more confidence in this approach. Also, with this approach, when the service is deleted, the ELB will not be delete by k8s.

Comment: OK, I will try #2.

Comment: I couldn't see that #2 is such a good idea, since I need to manually associate the ELB with the corresponding instances.

Comment: Could you explain more on "manually associate the ELB"? What did you do and what do you think is ideal?

Comment: When creating an ELB manually, I have to choose corresponding EC2 instances, so it looks like a chicken and egg problem.

Comment: I misunderstood you when you said "re-use an elastic load balancer", I was assuming you had ELB associated with instances already.

Comment: Does AWS has concepts like instance group? If so, you can create an instance group consists of k8s nodes, then it would be easier to create the ELB.

Comment: Dunno actually if it does.